# Why don't we have LaTeX?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

It is crucial to have LaTeX on this board, because we often need to talk about matrices and vectors e.g. while physics simulation. I think there are many themes like AI and other which require matematical symbols. Thanks.

Comment: This is basically not going to happen, as StackExchange considers the dependencies involved too expensive to deploy to sites outside of the Math SE.