# Game Development MathJax Cookbook

Tags: support, formatting, mathjax

MathJax (a relative of \$\LaTeX\$) is now enabled on this site. Mathematics.SE has [a MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but this question will be a cookbook for Game Development-specific mathematics formatting. Many posts in here will repeat or summarise content from that quick reference.

## Contributing to this cookbook

Please do so! Answers should each be a specific topic, or set of closely related topics. If in doubt, group them by how game development mathematicians would think of them. You can help in several ways:

- Revise existing answers to add or improve details, including formatting that isn't covered yet in that topic but ought to be.
- Expand an answer with new subsections covering tightly related topics that aren't covered yet.
- Post new answers about new topics, and link them in the table of contents in a position you feel is appropriate.

## Table of Contents

1. [Basic MathJax and Mathematics](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/2698)
2. [Vectors and Matrices](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2591/2698)
3. [Boolean Algebra and Logic](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2593/35344)
4. [Tables and arrays](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2594/2698)
5. [Tag and reference equations](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2709/2698)

Comment: I find [this](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) really useful, even when you know most of the markdown.

Answer (score 1):

## Vectors and Matrices

### Basic symbols

- `\vec` puts an arrow over the next symbol: \$\vec a\$. For larger groups, use `\overrightarrow`: \$\overrightarrow{abc}\$
- `\overleftrightarrow` and `\overleftarrow` are also available: \$ \overleftrightarrow{abc}\$ and \$\overleftarrow{abc}\$
- `\vert` and `\Vert` display single and double vertical bars: \$\vert a \vert\$ or \$\Vert a \Vert\$.

  - Strictly speaking, use `\lvert \rvert` and `\lVert \rVert` to display on the left and right sides of symbols respectively: \$\lvert a \rvert\$ and \$\lVert a \rVert\$. It may display more correctly certain formula renders.
- `\cdot` represents the centered dot for dot products: \$x \cdot y\$

### Matrices

The `\begin{matrix} ... \end{matrix}` environment facilitates display of a matrix. Separate matrix elements with `&` and create new matrix lines with `\\`. So the following code:

```
$$
\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix}
$$
```

produces

$$
\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix}
$$

To surround the matrix in brackets of some form, either use the `\left` and `\right` brackets from section 6 of the basic mathjax tutorial, or use pmatrix
\$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\$
, bmatrix
\$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\$
, Bmatrix
\$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{Bmatrix}
\$
, vmatrix
\$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
\$
, or Vmatrix
\$
\begin{Vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{Vmatrix}
\$.

You can use `\cdots` \$\cdots\$, `\ddots` \$\ddots\$, and `\vdots` \$\vdots\$ to omit entries.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & \cdots & e \\
c & d & \cdots & f \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & g \\
h & i & j & k
\end{pmatrix}
$$

## Vectors

Use a one-dimensional matrix. For example:

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

$$
\vec v =
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

## Basic MathJax and Mathematics

### Displaying a formula

For inline formulas, use `\$ ... \$`. For display-mode formulas (i.e. multiline, centered formulas which take up their own paragraph), use `$$ ... $$`. Various symbols will be displaye differently in inline vs multiline mode.

For example, the equation `\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}` renders in inline mode (`\$`) as the following: \$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}\$

Meanwhile in display mode (`$$`) it displays as: $$ \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} $$

(Note the `$$` also breaks it out into its own lines and centers it.)

**New lines:** Display formulas can have multiple lines. Insert a line break with `\\`.

### Grouping

MathJax operates on symbols or groups of symbols. Usually, a MathJax operator that's expecting to do something fancy with some symbols will grab just the very first symbol available and nothing more. For example, `a^bc` will be displayed as \$a^bc\$.

If we want to represent that as \$a\$ to the power of \$bc\$ we instead need to **group these symbols** using curly braces, i.e. `{ }`. So we'd write `a^{bc}` instead: \$a^{bc}\$.

You can get literal curly braces by escaping them: `\{foo\}` → \$ \{foo\} \$

### Basic mathematical formatting

1. **Mathematical operations:** `+`, `-` (hyphen), `\times` and `\div`: \$1 + 2 - 3 \times 4 \div 5\$.

   - `\cdot` for \$ x \cdot y \$
   - `\pm \mp` for \$\pm \mp\$
2. **Comparison:**

   - `\gt` and `\lt` for \$\gt\$ and \$\lt\$
   - `\ge` or `\geq` for \$\ge\$, `\geqslant` for \$\geqslant\$.
   - `\le` or `\leq` for \$\le\$, `\leqslant` for \$\leqslant\$
   - `\approx` `\sim` `\simeq` for \$\approx \sim \simeq\$
3. **Superscripts and subscripts:** use `^` and `_`. These can be combined: `x_i^2` or `x^2_i` renders as \$x_i^2\$.
4. **Fractions:**

   - `\frac a b` grabs the next two groups: \$\frac{a+1}{b+1}\$
   - `\dfrac a b` works the same but always occupies two lines of vertical space: \$\dfrac{a+1}{b+1}\$
   - You may instead prefer to use `\over`: `{a+1 \over b+1}` for \${a+1 \over b+1}\$
5. **Greek letters:** Use `\alpha`, `\beta`, …, `\omega`: \$\alpha, \beta \ldots \omega\$. For uppercase `\Gamma`, `\Delta`, …, `\Omega`: \$\Gamma, \Delta, \ldots \Omega\$.
6. **Plain text:** Usually all text is treated as symbols, so `these are some words` gets rendered as \$these are some words\$ despite the spaces. To tell MathJax to treat it as just ordinary text use `\text{stuff}`: \$\text{these are some words}\$.
7. **Floor and ceiling:** `\lfloor x \rfloor` for \$\lfloor x \rfloor\$, `\lceil x \rceil` for \$\lceil x \rceil\$

### Equation alignment

You can use the `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` environment to align equations over multiple lines. The `&` symbol is an alignment marker in this environment. Use `\\` to start new lines. The following example aligns on the equals sign:

```
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^2 + c^2 \\
a &= \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}
\end{align}
$$
```

$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^2 + c^2 \\
a &= \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}
\end{align}
$$

### Equation sizing

Occasionally the default mathjax sizing may need to be adjusted in order to make things readable. MathJax supports [size Latex commands](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Built-in_sizes):

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

The commands are listed from smallest to largest. `\normalsize` is the default. Note that use of capitalization on some commands.

The a size command is applied within the scope it occurs in. 
For example: `\${\Large\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_z^x}}}\$`
 
gives \${\Large\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_z^x}}}\$.

As a more practical example, the application `\small` allows the following to render without undesired line breaks:
$$f(t)={\small\frac{cos(rt)(gr^2_x+gr^2_y-r_xr^2_zv_y(0)+r_yr^2_zv_x(0)+
r^3_x(-v_y(0))+r^2_xr_yv_x(0)-r_xr^2_yv_y(0)+r^3_yv_x(0))}{r}}$$

Answer (score 1):

## Boolean Algebra and Logic

1. **Quantifiers.** use `\forall` and `\exists`: \$ \forall\ and \ \exists\ \$
2. **Operators.** use `\neg`, `\land` and `\lor`:  \$ \neg, \land\ and \lor\ \$

Answer (score 0):

## Tables and arrays

[The `array` environment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5044/119760) can do tables quite well.

```
$$
\begin{array}{r|lcl}
\text{Column One} & \text{Two} & \text{Three} & \text{Four} \\
\hline
foo & bar & baz & narf  \\
tinker & tailor & soldier & spy
\end{array}
$$
```

$$
\begin{array}{r|lcl}
\text{Column One} & \text{Two} & \text{Three} & \text{Four} \\
\hline
foo & bar & baz & narf  \\
tinker & tailor & soldier & spy
\end{array}
$$

There's several parts to this.

First, we begin the array (`\begin{array}`), then immediately make a column declaration: `{r|lcl}`. `r`, `l`, and `c`  define column alignment: right-aligned, left-aligned, centered. `|` establishes a vertical line between two columns. You can have `|`'s anywhere, including at the beginning or end, but multiple `|`s in a row are redundant.

Then we write out our rows. `&` separates the cells in a row. `\\` marks the end of the row.

We can insert a horizontal separator with `\hline`. This line doesn't need a `\\` at the end of it.

We end the array with `\end{array}`.

#### Boxing in a table

You can use `|` and `\hline` to completely box in a table, by placing lines at the start and end as well as between cells as you'd like:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

---

Advanced usage: you can use `\rlap` to [right-overlap a heading across several cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313640/47388)

$$
  \begin{array}{r|lll}
& \rlap{\text{number of foo}} \\
\text{number of bar} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
0 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168 \\
1 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168 \\
2 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.168
  \end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

## Tag and reference equations

### Tagging

If you have multiple equations in the same post, you may want to tag them for reference using `\tag`. For example, `\tag{1}` adds this floaty \$(1)\$ on the right hand side here:

$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \tag{1}  \label{eq1} $$

```
$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \tag{1} $$
```

You can also use letters, whole words, and so on.

Usually a MathJax block can only contain one tag. The Align environment lets you add multiple tags should you want:

$$
\begin{align}
c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \tag 1 \\
c &= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \tag 2
\end{align}
$$

```
$$
\begin{align}
c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \tag 1 \\
c &= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
```

### Referencing equations in code

Your primary use case for tags might be referenceing your equations in code examples, to show what mathematics you're implementing:

[image: python code implementing the pythagorean theorem for a triangle, with an "#equation 2" comment to reference the above equation]

### Referencing equations via a MathJax link

If you want to reference (and link back to) the equation elsewhere in your post, add a `\label` as well. I'll call this one `eq3`:

$$ c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \tag{3} \label{eq3} $$

```
$$ c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \tag{3} \label{eq3} $$
```

Then reference it using `\eqref{eq3}`: \eqref{eq3}. Note that the link text is \$(3)\$ because that is the tag text. If I had given this equation `\tag{foo}` instead then the eqref text here woud be \$(\text{foo})\$. The purpose of this link is to scroll the particular equation into view, so here's a link back to the very first equation on this post, to which I sneakily added a label, for a better example: \eqref{eq1}.

Labels must be unique: two equations can't share the same label.