# Can we have syntax highlighting on meta?

Tags: feature-request, meta

The following code example on meta renders without any syntax highlighting, despite a syntax highlighting directive:

```
from math import sqrt

class Triangle:
    def hypotenuse(self):
        # equation 2
        return sqrt(self.a**2 + self.b**2)
```

(The directive used here is `<!-- language: lang-py -->`.)

On mainsite it renders fairly prettily:

[image: the same code example with pretty colored syntax highlighting]

The lack of syntax highlighting impacts the readability of meta documentation, such as in [this Mathjax documentation here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2709/2698) which includes the above  Python block — as a screenshot, not as an actual code block, so as to get the code syntax highlighted properly to demonstrate what this would look like mainsite.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like there **is** syntax highlighting on SO meta; when I did a quick copy / paste of this question over there, the preview rendered both with color coding.