# Do we want to update the link to the MathJax help in the help pages? If so, to where?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hyperlinks, mathjax

It's been recently brought to our attention that Stack Exchange staff can change the *Learn more: MathJax help.* link in the [Markdown help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help) section [LaTeX](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

- It currently points to an external site: [An Introduction to Latex](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/).
- Some Stack Exchange communities have had their link point to a Meta post on Mathematics Stack Exchange: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
- We have our own [Game Development MathJax Cookbook](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/game-development-mathjax-cookbook). Please note that this meta post also links to the aforementioned Meta post on Mathematics.
- If these options are not interesting for us, we could still come up with something better.

So, what should we do?

Comment: I have posted the approach I prefer, so feel free to add another answer if your opinion differs.

Comment: Added to the CMs' backlog — you'll get an update when someone picks it up.

Comment: I updated the link to point to the site suggested by Vaillancourt.

Comment: @SpencerG Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think having the link point to an external site is bad per se, but since we already have one nicely done on our side, I think we should **update it to our own [Game Development MathJax Cookbook](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/game-development-mathjax-cookbook)**.

Comment: Agree with this one.