# Markdown support for tables

Tags: discussion

All sites across Stack Exchange are now able to use [tables via Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/228147)!

Do we need a "to do" list similar to our [MathJax PSA](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/33287)? 
If so then add it here as an answer. 
If not, just keep the functionality in mind when editing & posting.

Comment:  tables! But I'm not sure we need such a post, though; that being said, you can have it if you think it's useful and you want to use it as a reminder of all the work that needs to be done here :)